# Maple summation notation issue: differentiating with respect to an indexed value

Tags: summation, partial-derivative, maple

I am trying to solve a summation equation, for the derivative with respect to x[0], where x is a vector of numbers.

If I try something like this:

diff(sum(x[k]*f(k), k = 0 .. m)+sum(x[s]*f(s^2), s = 0 .. m),x[0])
[image: example1]

I get the response "0" from Maple.

To give scope on exactly why I am trying to do, and why some very naive solutions haven't worked for me (e.g. just enumerating it out to some constant)   I'm doing something more like this (where the summations are interleaved, and inside and out of functions):

```
sum((sum(unary[r][u]*g[u](w[r]*(sum(unaryi[r][ui]*g[ui](wi[r]*inputi[r]), ui)+sum(sum(binaryi[r][bi]*f[bi](srcWi[r][si]*inputi[si], wi[r]*inputi[r]), si), bi))), u)+sum(sum(binary[r][b]*f[b](srcW[r][s]*(sum(unaryi[s][ui]*g[ui](wi[s]*inputi[r]), ui)+sum(sum(binaryi[s][bi]*f[bi](srcWi[s][si]*inputi[si], wi[s]*inputi[s]), si), bi)), w[r]*(sum(unaryi[r][ui]*g[ui](wi[r]*inputi[r]), ui)+sum(sum(binaryi[r][bi]*f[bi](srcWi[r][si]*inputi[si], wi[r]*inputi[r]), si), bi))), s), b)-answer[r])^2, r)
```

[image]

I'm trying to find the derivative of that with respect to srcWi[0][0], and many of the other indexed variables, 6 of them to be exact.

EDIT: another issue is just how many variable substitutions are required just to set one of the subscripts to 0!

Update: Things are getting harder, mostly because I have to manually go through and simplify summations each time, I have to look for patterns and similarities and I am making couple mistakes as a go along, I don't actually use maple often either. Quite tedious. I'll be printing out a couple versions today, to see if I can put this to rest!

Update2: Problem in complexity appears to be the issue is that the summation disappears and I need to infer where the summation SHOULD be, so I have to collapse all these equations carefully and correctly.

Update3: haven't made much progress yet, I should have by now

Comment: We are humans, not Maple code processors.

Comment: my apologies, i thought the one above would be sufficient to show the question i was trying to ask. I can supply an image as a temporary solution before learning mathjax

Comment: A low-level answer to why Maple returns $0$ is that the variable $x_0$ does not literally appear in the expression being differentiated.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me if I'm being daft, but when you take the derivative with respect to $x_{0}$, all the other terms disappear, correct? So
$$\frac{d}{dx_{0}} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{m} x_{k}f(k) + \sum_{x=0}^{k} x_{s}f(s^{2})\right)
= \frac{d}{dx_{0}} \left( x_{0}f(0) + x_{0}f(0) \right) = \frac{d}{dx_{0}} 2x_{0}f(0) = 2f(0),$$
assuming that $f$ is not a function of $x_{0}$.

It should be the same in your big ugly formula, you can just ignore all the terms where your variable of interest does not appear.

**[Edit:]** Probably what you need to do, is to define your big summation as a multivariate polynomial, and compute it out (determine all coefficients). Then once you have that polynomial, Maple shouldn't complain about taking the derivative with respect to a given variable. (Disclosure: I don't use Maple, but this is what I would do in Magma)

Comment: you are absolutely correct! however... the more advanced example isn't as easy

Comment: okay you might be right, the biggest issue i gues is how tedious that can be since i have several instances of each variable, some even with different names, then I need to subsitute in the right subscript for everybody else... and then I want to do this for srcW, w, unaryi, wi, unaryi, binaryi, binary. That's a lot of little subsitutions